# Microsoft Graph which outlook versions are supported?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-calendar

I need to synchronize my application's calendar with client outlook calendar. My clients may have Outlook 2002-Outlook 2016 and Outlook 365. Does Microsoft Graphs REST calendar API support all these versions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The version of Outlook or any mail client isn't what determines compatibility with Microsoft Graph. Outlook is just a client that connects to an Exchange mail server.  Graph works with Office 365 and on-prem Exchange 2016. Hybrid support (Microsoft Graph connecting to an on-prem Exchange server) is documentated at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/hybrid_rest_support

Comment: Is it possible for on-premise servers to block api calls?

Comment: The article says only v1.0 of the Mail, Calendar and Contacts API are available for mailboxes in hybrid deployments. I read v1.0 support will be deprecated in Nov 2018 (https://dev.office.com/blogs/outlook-rest-api-v1-0-office-365-discovery-and-live-connect-api-deprecation).  Will the hybrid deployment continue to work in v2.0?